# How to add a dividier to an javascript object when a value changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching data from firestore using reactjs. As there is no issue I just replaced it with an array of objects. Each object has a `timeStampString`. I want to track the change of that value and add a divider if the value changes.

```
import React from 'react';

function MyView() {

    const fetchedData = [
       {
            foo: "Foo",
            timeStampString: "20200831"
       },
       {
            foo: "Foo",
            timeStampString: "20200831"
       },
       // change of timeStampString happening here v
       {
            foo: "Foo",
            timeStampString: "20200830"
       },
       {
            foo: "Foo",
            timeStampString: "20200830"
       },
    ];

    return (
        <div>
             {fetchedData.map((data) => (
                 <>
                     { // THE NEXT LINE IS JUST MY TRY }
                     { data.timeStamp !== the.one.before ? "<div className=\"divider\"></div>" : "" } 
                     <div>{data.foo} - {data.timeStampString}</div>
                 </>
             ))};
        </div>
    );
}
export default MyView;
```

How can I add a divider when the `timeStampString` changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the previous index in the `fetchData` array, check if it exists and compare the strings if it does. Then render the div with an [inline if statement](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator).

```
return (
  <div>
    {fetchedData.map((data, i) => {
      const previous = fetchedData[i - 1];
      return (
        <>
          {previous && data.timeStampString !== previous.timeStampString && (
            <div className="divider"></div> 
          )} 
          <div>{data.foo} - {data.timeStampString}</div>
        </>
      )
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create variables to see if the variable changed like this:

```
import React from "react";

function MyView() {
  const fetchedData = [
    {
      foo: "Foo",
      timeStampString: "20200831",
    },
    {
      foo: "Foo",
      timeStampString: "20200831",
    },
    // change of timeStampString happening here v
    {
      foo: "Foo",
      timeStampString: "20200830",
    },
    {
      foo: "Foo",
      timeStampString: "20200830",
    },
  ];
  let timeStampSave = null
  return (
    <div>
      {fetchedData.map((data) => {
        let isChanged = timeStampSave !== null && timeStampSave !== data.timeStamp;
        timeStampSave = data.timeStamp;
        return (
          <>
            {isChanged ? '<div className="divider"></div>' : ""}
            <div>
              {data.foo} - {data.timeStampString}
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
      ;
    </div>
  );
}
export default MyView;
```